# Html ActionLink isn't displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm showing a small table with a list of usernames, and I want an ActionLink next to each username to Edit the user on another page.

Here's my view page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WebUI.Models.IndexModel>>" %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><% Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Employee", new { id = item.UserID }, null); %></td>
        <td><%: item.Username %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

My controller methods in EmployeeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<IndexModel> model = new List<IndexModel>();

    //load model with data

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    return View();
}
```

My model:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

The usernames display correctly, just the link doesn't show up. I'm not sure why it wouldn't throw an error instead.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the `;` and adding `:` before-

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Employee", new { id = item.UserID }, null) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a : in your code.
Try this:

```
<td><%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Employee", new { id = item.UserID }, null) %></td>
```

EDIT: Removed the ; at the end didn't notice it earlier.